# Using TweenMax on multiple elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gsap

I have an Angular treeview directive I'm working on that doesn't include jQuery. I'm using TweenMax to open and close the branches of the tree. It seems that TweenMax only works with id's. I can only open and close the top branch right now with the id "list". I have multiple branches I need to target and I dont have jQuery to help with classes. Is there a work around for this? Here is the link to my code in [CodePen.io](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tdIjl)

Here is the directive:

```
var tree = angular.module('treeview',[]);

tree.directive('treeView',function(){
return{
    restrict: 'AE',

    link:function (scope,elem,attrs){

        var list = TweenMax.from("#list",0.5,{height:0,paused:true,reversed:true});

            function toggle(){
                // e.preventDefault();
                if (list.reversed()) {
                    list.play();
                  } else {
                    list.reverse();
                  }

            }

        elem.on('click',function(e){


            toggle();


            e.stopPropagation();
        });

    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an HTML element to the `TweenMax.from` function as well as a selector (see [documentation](http://greensock.com/get-started-js)). Note also that angular includes a stripped back version of jQuery called jQuery lite which you can use to wrap an element and run a limited subset of jQuery's functions on it ([documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)).

There may be a neater way of doing this, but you can do what you're trying to do by applying the techniques above as follows (updated [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AIlHE)):

```
var tree = angular.module('treeview',[]);
tree.directive('treeView',function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'AE',
        link:function (scope,elem,attrs){

            // Use jQuery lite to access the first child of the scoped element
            var ul = angular.element(elem).children(0);
            var list = TweenMax.from(ul,0.5,{height:0,paused:true,reversed:true});

            function toggle(){
                if (list.reversed()) {
                    list.play();
                  } else {
                    list.reverse();
                  }  
            }

            elem.on('click',function(e){
                toggle();
                e.stopPropagation();
            });
        }
    }
});
```